# Avoid hyphenation around a specific character

Tags: hyphenation

I want to use typographic apostrophe (’) in my document. Using a simple ' don't give the same result.

I can type the ’ on my keyboard. But XeTeX take it as a normal character, ie. like a letter, and it can generate bad hyphenation like this (using the [xmemoire class](https://gitorious.org/memoire/)) :

```
\documentclass{xmemoire}
\usepackage{wrapfig} 
\lccode`\’=0
\begin{document}
\begin{wrapfigure}{R}[1cm]{0.33\linewidth}
         \begin{center}
          \caption{{\normalfont { Logo associé à l’\textit{ERC Starting Grants} d’Analyse de la maturation cérébrale.}}}
          \label{figbb}
        \end{center}
\end{wrapfigure}
\end{document}
```

How do I avoid hyphenation around ’, or more generally around a given character, in all the document (I know I can use mbox for local forcing).

Comment: Make a small, but complete example that demonstrates your problem. Also tell us the version of your xetex and the packages.

Comment: Are you using a package like Babel or Polyglossia with which you can get the language of the document?  Those packages should prevent hyphenation at apostrophes as you are encountering.

Comment: With `\usepackage{polyglossia}\setmainlanguage{french}` I get only `l’apos-trophe`.

Comment: Here is a simple example which reproduce my problem, I use [xmemoire](https://gitorious.org/memoire/) as document class (sorry but it seems I can't insert new lines in comments): \documentclass{xmemoire}
    \usepackage{wrapfig} 

    \begin{document}
    \begin{wrapfigure}{R}[1cm]{0.33\linewidth}
             \begin{center}
              \caption{{\normalfont { Logo associé à l’\textit{ERC Starting Grants} d’Analyse de la maturation cérébrale.}}}
              \label{figbb}
            \end{center}
    \end{wrapfigure}
    \end{document}

Comment: My XeTeX version : This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)

Comment: Yes: with that old version of TeX Live it can happen. The best thing you can do is to upgrade: http://tug.org/texlive

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like

```
\lccode`\’=0
```

should turn that character into a symbol not considered as a word constituent.  Note that I don't really have experience with XeTeX: this is based on the assumption that XeTeX will treat characters beyond 8bit just like below.

Comment: @user9588 How to obtain the same result with a combining character, like acute combining character, unicode '0301' ?